# Not a directory @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/bin/fuzzy_match

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, mobile

Im trying to install Cocoapods on macOS mojave with these terminal command $ sudo gem install cocoapods

**and im getting this error**

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error on a build machine, but it turned out that a previous install of jamf (Enterprise Mac management software) had mangled the /usr/local/bin folder, and had turned it into a symbolic link to a file.

It appears that on your system /usr/local/bin/fuzzy_match is not a real folder. Try inspecting the path and see if /usr/local/bin/ is still valid.